# Objects are shuffled. What is the probability that exactly one object remains in its original position?

Tags: combinatorics

We have a deck with $n$ cards enumerated $1,2,\ldots,n$. The deck is shuffled. What is the probability of exactly one card to remain on its original position? What is the limit as $n$ rises to infinity?

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\{1\} & : & \dfrac 11 \\[6pt]
\{12,21\} & : & \dfrac 02 \\[6pt]
\{123,132,213,231,312,321\} & : & \dfrac 36 \\[6pt]
& \vdots
\end{array}
$$

At $n = 100 0$ and $10 000$ trials:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\text{value of }n & & \text{probability} \\
\hline
1000 & & 0.3739 \\
1001 & & 0.3689 \\
1002 & & 0.3722 \\
1003 & & 0.3638 \\
1004 & & 0.3707 \\
1005 & & 0.3664 \\
1006 & & 0.3616 \\
1007 & & 0.3728 \\
1008 & & 0.3702 \\
1009 & & 0.3801
\end{array}
$$

At $n = 100 000$ and $10 000$ trials:

> $\text{value of } n \quad \text{probability}$
>
> $\quad 100000 \quad \quad 0.3659$
>
> $\quad 100001 \quad \quad 0.3552$
>
> $\quad 100002 \quad \quad 0.356$
>
> $\quad 100003 \quad \quad 0.367$
>
> $\quad 100004 \quad \quad 0.3738$
>
> $\quad 100005 \quad \quad 0.3647$
>
> $\quad 100006 \quad \quad 0.3654$
>
> $\quad 100007 \quad \quad 0.3637$
>
> $\quad 100008 \quad \quad 0.3718$
>
> $\quad 100009 \quad \quad 0.3708$

Apparently, probability approaches $0.36-0.38$, but how can one derive it analytically?

Comment: Looks like you were in the a very similar boat as me: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6140/2333

Comment: If n is 2 there is no solution :-P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To find the number of "good" permutations fix one card and derange the rest $(n-1)$ cards. This can be done in $!n$ ways. ($!n$ is the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $n$ objects). Then the number of "good" permutations is $n\cdot !(n-1)$. Hence we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n\cdot !(n-1)}{n!} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{!(n-1)}{(n-1)!} = e^{-1}$$

The last limit can be seen in the link I added above.

Comment: Isn't this overcounting the cases where two or more cards are in their original position?

Comment: @Taemyr The term "derangement" means that the other n-1 cards have a position different from their original one. This is why it's $!(n-1)$, not $(n-1)!$.

Answer (score 11):

By the inclusion-exclusion principle, in the symmetric group $S_n$ there are
$$ n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} $$
permutations without fixed points (see [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)). It follows that in the same group there are
$$ n\cdot (n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} $$
elements with exactly one fixed point, and the limit probability is $\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{e}}$ in both cases.

Comment: Then the limit probability of _at most_ one fixed point is $\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{e}=\frac{2}{e}$. And for two fixed points?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: correct. The probability of having exactly two fixed points is given by $$\frac{1}{n!}\binom{n}{2}(n-2)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\to\color{red}{\frac{1}{2e}}$$ and the limit probability of having exactly $k$ fixed points is $\frac{1}{k! e}$.

Comment: Yes, I was just realizing that. Thanks.

Comment: In other words, as $n \to \infty$ the number of fixed points of a random permutation of $n$ elements converges in distribution to a Poisson(1) random variable.